# Check state of and information about an external application

Tags: java, desktop-application

Here (http://www.desktop-macros.com/) is a program which records sequences of mouse clicks and key strokes on a PC and then plays it back to perform some user-defined actions.

Now, what I'd like to achieve is a bit more demanding: I'd like for example to launch a browser with mouse clicks, **wait until it's started** (i.e. its application screen is visible) and then again perform some mouse&keyboard actions.

Of course it would also be useful to obtain also other information, like position and dimensions of the window.

Is it possible to make such fancy OS-related operations (like checking whether an application is fully-loaded) with Java? Maybe there are some non-standard libraries with useful API?

If not, could you recommend some way/language of solving such an issue?

Comment: OFF TOPIC, Answer for your question that was just deleted: From [help format](www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html):

       format hex, intmax('uint64'), realmax
    shows ffffffffffffffff and 7fefffffffffffff respectively.
    The HEX display corresponds to the internal representation of the value
    and is not the same as the hexadecimal notation in the C programming
    language.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) that has the command `WinWait` that waits for windows having the good title. But I rely on `Send {Enter}`, not on mouse, to do things.